# What should I choose: GTK+ or Qt?

Tags: linux, qt, gtk

Can someone suggest what's the best uses for those libraries today? Is it just GUI, or do they have database, XML, networking, threading, etc support too?

I was reading about them, and considered starting to learning/using one of them.

What is the most common one? What's the difference between them? Why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: Originally, there was a lot of controversy about the Qt licensing model that was either full GPL or commercial, while GTK+ was LGPL (so the latter was easier to use in combination with your closed source product). But now Qt is also available as LGPL IIRC, so that's not a real reason anymore to choose one or another.

Comment: You might also look at this mostly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801074/what-are-the-differences-between-gtk-and-qt

Comment: And again a good question closed on stackoverflow.

I want to add that if you need a good integrated HTML widget you have to use GTK now (after QT 5.2 moved to a dramatically/unuseable reduced feature set) or use QT and embed the Chrome CEF which is adding lots of stuff, complication and 20MB to your app.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

As you seem to primarily target Linux, then the choice mostly depends on the programming language you want to use.

If you code in C, then obviously go for GTK+

If you code in C++, go for Qt, otherwise you will need [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/) (a C++ wrapper over GTK+)

If you code in Python, both GTK+ and Qt have bindings for the language: see [PyGtk](http://www.pygtk.org/), [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) and [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) (the one launched by Nokia themselves).

If you code in Java, Qt is no more a viable option imho as [Nokia discontinued Qt Jambi](https://web.archive.org/web/20090221105007/http://www.qtsoftware.com/about/news/preview-of-final-qt-jambi-release-available) (the Java bindings for Qt).

Also, Qt is more top-notch regarding its scenegraph [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) API, its scripting engine built over Javascript Core (the engine powering WebKit), its state machine and animations framework, and the [declarative UI](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/05/13/qt-declarative-ui/).

GTK+ doesn't offer that much although you can use [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) alongside with it.

If you're specifically looking into DB, XML (GTK+ has a parser for a subset of XML) and threading (GTK+ has [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/)) features then Qt will offer all that in [QtSql](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html), [QtXml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-index.html) and [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html).

All in all, I would say Qt is a sure choice. But GTK+ is very capable as well.

I'm not sure you will get a crystal clear answer for your question, which explains why some people keep preferring Gnome over KDE or vice-versa. **Choose what works best for you.**

PS: I you plan to also target Symbian, then go for Qt.

EDIT: Something that is also great with Qt is `QtWebView`: it brings Chromium into your Qt application to display web content. Others are embedding web content into their application using for instance Awesomium or Berkelium.

Comment: Don't forget that QtScript is powered by JavaScriptCore, which is currently the fastest JavaScript engine thanks to SquirrelFish Extreme.

Comment: Regarding your edit, there is WebKitGtk+ for GTK+. Unless one is substantially more mature than the other, I don't think the existence of QtWebKit qualifies as an advantage over GTK+.

Comment: If you code in **Ruby** look for [QtRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtRuby).

Comment: As for [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/) for **Java**, although official support by Nokia ended years ago, the project is currently maintained by an open source community.

Comment: `gtkmm` is great, all the power of GTK+ but using _actual_ C++ by the modern definition, producing the cleanest, most readable GUI code I've seen... actually, just the most _bearable_, because when I first started trying to learn GUI programming, it was the neatness of `gtkmm` that restored my will to live. Thankfully, perseverence paid off, and I found out that it's extremely powerful, and it encouraged me to get more into C++14 than C++03. Also, it's well-maintained, by the same primary maintainer for over a decade AFAICT. I'm just a fan, no affiliation, etc.

Comment: Oh... the Symbian days ...

Comment: There's no reason to not pick GTK+, just because you're using C++. GTK+ is still object oriented and doesn't exactly clash with C++. Qt reinvents most of the standard C++ library anway, so it's not like you lose anything by picking GTK+ in that regard.

Answer (score 47):

I've used GTK+, QT and wxWidgets before. Here's a brief summary:

For my first cross platform UI project I decided to go for wxWidgets mainly because at the time the license wasn't as restrictive as QT's (QT was GPL and only for Linux) and it had platform specific UI (unlike GTK). The project worked out well but there were quite a few glitches getting it to compile and run properly in other platforms - sometimes some events were fired up differently and such. Also GDI in wxWidgets was pretty slow.

Next I used GTK for a different project in python. For this I used the python bindings and everything worked out more or less smoothly. I didn't quite like the fact that the UI didn't look native on Windows and Mac and also when you launch a GTK+ app it always debug outputs loads of CRITICAL warnings which seem fine to ignore. :S

Finally, I did a very simple QT project now that Nokia has acquired it and was brilliant. The best of the three. First off, if you're not an old schooler who prefers VI or Emacs, QtCreator is brilliant. I really love VI and used it for years but I much prefer QtCreator for C++ QT projects. Regarding the library I also liked a lot the documentation and the APIs provided. QT has a concept of slots and signals which introduce new C++ keywords and a preprocessor. Basically, after reading a tutorial you'll get it easily and will start to love it. I'm now doing iPhone dev and it does feel a bit like Cocoa's/Interface Builder's UI paradigm.

Summary: I'd go for QT hands down. The license is pretty good and the SDK and documentation really nice.

Comment: I consider it a positive that GTK+ applications look the same on different platforms as it means I don't have to spend extra weeks figuring out how to make my UIs arrange themselves exactly right with each native toolkit. Also - `when you launch a GTK+ app it always debug outputs loads of CRITICAL warnings which seem fine to ignore. :S`- no, it doesn't, unless you're doing something wrong, which is **not** fine. I've never once seen a critical warning that didn't stem from an oops of my own and wasn't extremely easy to fix by using correct code. And I get _no_ debug messages, not even warnings

Answer (score 28):

I have never used GTK, but from my personal experience using Qt:

It is much more than a simple GUI.  It's a whole application framework.  I used to think of it as the Java libraries for C++.  It provides all you mention -- database, XML, networking and threading, and more.  It also provides things such as containers and iterators, and counterparts to a number of boost libraries.

The thing that impressed me most when starting to use Qt was the extremely extensive documentation.  You get a program called Qt Assistant, which provides fully indexed and searchable API documentation on your desktop, as well as numerous code examples and tutorials.  I found it made a big difference in searching the web each time for API info.  Very quick access when you need to remember a method signature.

I am not sure which is most common; that's probably hard to measure accurately.  They're certainly both popular.  As Gnome is the default desktop of Ubuntu, and Gnome sits on top of GTK, it obviously has widespread usage.  Of course, KDE is very popular as well.  Nokia is heavily pushing Qt in the mobile space -- their Maemo OS, used on the new N900 for example, is soon to switch to Qt as the default toolkit (currently it is GTK.)  I believe Qt will also soon become the default toolkit for Symbian OS.

I have not used Qt Creator, but I have heard many good things about it.  It is a C++ IDE with obvious heavy integration with Qt.  It also has fake vim emulation which is always nice if you like that kind of thing!

Qt uses qmake for build configuration.  I found this much nicer than having to write your own makefiles. I do not know what GTK uses for building.

A couple of things I found a bit offputting with Qt at first was its big uses of preprocessor macros.  The signal/slots system provides a nice mechanism for event/message passing in your application, but it does feel a bit like magic that may not be easily portable to another toolkit if you ever want to. Also, the moc (meta-object compiler), while I'm not entirely sure what it does, also feels a bit too much like magic going on behind the scenes.

All in all, though, I would recommend Qt, particularly if you are learning.  It has really amazing documentation and a nice IDE, and busy forums.  You'll be able to build C++ apps very rapidly with it, particularly with the QML coming in 4.7.

Answer (score 9):

It probably depends on what you want to do. I would recommend Qt, because it's more than GUI, it has nice Python bindings (so does Gtk), and GUI libraries themselves are (subjectively speaking) more pleasant then Gtk.

Gtk is on the other hand more common in linux world, so you can probably get more help on the web. Reason for widespread of Gtk probably has more to do with Gnome and Ubuntu, rather then technical merits, but if you want you software to blend nicely with those two, you'll achieve that more easily with Gtk.

Answer (score 8):

Qt for one sure has solid DB, network, threading support etc... It does a lot more then just cross-platform GUI (and it does most of it quite well).

I'd recommend it over GTK+.

Answer (score 4):

Qt. It's not only object oriented, is "good" object oriented.
It's based on a "subset" of C++ that doesn't rely on the obscurity of C++ (but you are allowed to stick with them, if you fancy masochism ;) ).

It has a strong momentum now that Nokia bought it (actually Nokia did ~2/3 years ago). It's going to be in all Nokia AND Intel mobile devices (smartphones, netbooks, tablets).

It's the backbone of KDE, so it's very mature, but it's designed in a very flexible way, that makes it possible to support TODAY all the latest "cool stuff" that a **more-then-just-GUI** framework should have.

Go for it.

Comment: Subset? More like superset, considering qmake and moc.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding QT advantages to other answers.. QT has great documentation, its own [IDE & GUI creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) and enhances C++ with some new concepts like slots/signals (basically events).

I am not a GTK developer, so I can't compare those to the GTK world :(

Comment: For Gtk, there also exist a GUI creator Glade (http://glade.gnome.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like Nokia is about to use Qt everywhere, like on Maemo

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app to run on iOS, Android, Blackberry, other mobile platforms, Windows, Mac OSX, and Linux, use Qt.

[qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org)