# What's easier and cleaner? GTK or QT?

Tags: qt, gtk, pygtk, pyqt4, gtk#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I choose: GTK+ or Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887070/what-should-i-choose-gtk-or-qt)

What's easier to understand and more natural, faster to master, pleasant to use every day with different languages - the latest version of GTK or QT?

The question may be a bit subjective and hollyWar-ish, but interesting, significant and possible to answer objectively, I believe.

Comment: There are certainly some objective comparisons you can make between GTK and QT (features, execution speed, license, ...) but the suggestions in your question for ways to compare them all seem to be very subjective. What you think is natural depends mostly on what you are used to.

Comment: I hardly bother about the difference in execution speed of those and don't bother about licenses at all (it's like just for fun :-) ). I am only interested in ease and naturality of use, learning curve, feature richness, versatility, community support, quantity of mature enough free extra widgets projects, etc.

Comment: I've just migrated from Windows to Linux and tried GTK# with Mono, and it looks pretty weird to me after 10 years of Windows forms (VB, ActiveX, VCL, .Net WinForms, Java Swing, WPF).

Comment: This is hardly objective and mostly a personal opinion. But having have worked with GTK+, GTK+ 2, Qt 3 and Qt 4. I have grown to love Qt, Qt 3 was already pretty good but Qt 4 is even a large improvement over that. GTK+ was horrible imho and although GTK+ 2 is definately much better, it's still no match imho. Qt has the only graphical designer I have found tolerable and I think the docs are very good.

Comment: Ivan, I've used both Gtk+ and WinForms. Gtk+ is a completely different mindset, but I think you'll find that once you get your head around it, it is easier to create great-looking programs with it than with WinForms. Primarily this is because Gtk+ is all about layout and packing. WinForms (imo), is more or less geared to placing things with absolute coordinates, and it is harder to make everything behave properly when the whole form changes size.

Comment: Duplicate question: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801074/what-are-the-differences-between-gtk-and-qt, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887070/what-should-i-choose-gtk-or-qt and several others.