# starting with GTK+ on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gtk, apt-get

I am just beginning with GTK+.

I have an Ubuntu 11.04. How should I install the GTK and which stable version?

The GTK website offers packages for download. However there are 4 other supporting packages. I was wondering if I can us sudo apt-get or synaptic to download them. When I typed GTK on Synaptic there is a long list though.

Please suggest a stable GTK version available for download using sudo apt-get.

Also, what IDE should I use for development and simulation?

I have been programming with Qt till now which had the QtCreator, QtDesigner for this purpose. My Application has to now be ported on GTK. I googled to find out no translator engine for Qt to GTK.

Did any of you have this experience?

Thanks

Comment: For downloading gtk3.0 stable version for Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
I could compile some sample gtk+ examples after this.

Comment: just curious as to why was this closed..? was it due to vagueness of question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install two different versions (2.24.10, 3.4.1) of GTK+ on Ubuntu (precise).

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Examples and demo application can be installed by the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2.0-examples
sudo apt-get install gtk-3-examples
```

There is no IDE like QtCreator in case of Qt, but there is a user interface builder named Glade.

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

Comment: Thanks to you. +1 for the glade :)

Answer (score 1):

If your background is Qt, which is a C++ API, you should probably go straight for [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/), which is the official C++ bindings for GTK+. This is needed since at heart, GTK+ is a C API, which relies on *bindings* to make the toolkit available in other programming languages than C.

I would not expect there to be a 1:1 translation tool, either, so your porting might become quite labor-intensive. I hope you don't need to continue to support the Qt version, too.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801074/what-are-the-differences-between-gtk-and-qt) seems to be relevant, and have good answers that seem worth reading for someone in your position.

Answer (score 0):

[Anjuta](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/) is the defacto IDE for development on the Gnome platform using GTK. You can install it on Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get install anjuta
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if there is an eclipse plugin for GTK+ development?